# When I hit the submit button, I'm unable to achieve the, "Enjoy your day" on the entire screen after one or all the checkboxes have been checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Checklist</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Checklist</h1>
  <form onsubmit="return isChecked()">
    <div class="workout>">
      <input type="checkbox" id="workout" name="todo1" value="workout">workout</input>
    </div>
    <div class="meeting">
      <input type="checkbox" id="meeting" name="todo2" value="meeting">meeting</input>
    </div>
    <div class="lunch">
      <input type="checkbox" id="lunch" name="todo3" value="lunch">lunch</input>
    </div>
    <div class="school">
      <input type="checkbox" id="school" name="todo4" value="school">class</input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"
        onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()">
    </div>
    <!--<p id="msg"></p> (I tried using this approach and calling the msg within script but I received an error.)-->
  </form>
  </div>
</body>


<script>
  function isChecked() {
    var workout = document.getElementById('workout').checked;
    var meeting = document.getElementById('meeting').checked;
    var lunch = document.getElementById('lunch').checked;
    var school = document.getElementById('school').checked;
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    var text = document.getElementById('msg');
```

//My if/else statement alert works perfectly. However, with the presence of const submit, it doesn't work properly (I think it's interfering with my if/else statement). Removing the const submit section allows one to experience the if/else alert statement. The goal of this checklist is to be able to check one or all four checkboxes and have it return the "Enjoy your day" text. However, I would like for that message to cover the screen and be the only thing visible after hitting the submit button. I'm okay with receiving an alert box when it returns false. However, when it returns true, I would like for the message to cover the screen and for the checklist/checkboxes to disappear. I'm not sure where I'm getting my wires crossed.

```
    if (workout == false && meeting == false && lunch == false && school == false) {
      alert('Please check a box');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Enjoy your day.</h1>";
    });
  }
</script>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d0He.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdTh3.png)

Comment: submit buttons do not have a change event. You should not be binding the submit event inside of `isChecked`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring ***submit*** twice in the ***isChecked*** function. Omit one of the declaration.

Also, you are adding the event listener to the submit button after the return statement, which JS will ignore and won't append any onclick function.

The updated ***isChecked*** function should be

```
function isChecked() {
    var workout = document.getElementById('workout').checked;
    var meeting = document.getElementById('meeting').checked;
    var lunch = document.getElementById('lunch').checked;
    var school = document.getElementById('school').checked;
    // Removed the submit variable
    var text = document.getElementById('msg');
    if (workout == false && meeting == false && lunch == false && school == false) {
        alert('Please check a box');
        return false;
    }
    const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Enjoy your day.</h1>";
    });
    // Returning true after adding the event listener.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `addEventListener` should not be inside of that....

Comment: Yeah, @epascarello I agree with you. Assuming how the form should behave the implementation seems wrong to me as well. He is trying to add a click event to submit button and also a submit event on the form. I feel the onsubmit event should be changed with a function that will validate the values of the checkbox and show the alert or "Enjoy your day!" message accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That makes sense and I have made that syntax change. But @epascarello how do I retrieve the message as depicted in image 2 (click on enter image description here) to be displayed after clicking the submit button, following checking one or all checkboxes?

Comment: @epascarello For purposes of presentation, I simply created an h1 tag for "Enjoy your day" so viewers could see the end result regarding the function of the app. Image for this is located under enter image description here.

Answer (score 0):

Just display the message since it is being called onsubmit

```js
function isChecked() {
  var workout = document.getElementById('workout').checked;
  var meeting = document.getElementById('meeting').checked;
  var lunch = document.getElementById('lunch').checked;
  var school = document.getElementById('school').checked;

  if (!workout && !meeting && !lunch && !school) {
    alert('Please check a box');
  } else {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Enjoy your day.</h1>";
  }

  return false;

}
```

```html
<h1>Checklist</h1>
<form onsubmit="return isChecked()">
  <div class="workout>">
    <input type="checkbox" id="workout" name="todo1" value="workout">workout</input>
  </div>
  <div class="meeting">
    <input type="checkbox" id="meeting" name="todo2" value="meeting">meeting</input>
  </div>
  <div class="lunch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="lunch" name="todo3" value="lunch">lunch</input>
  </div>
  <div class="school">
    <input type="checkbox" id="school" name="todo4" value="school">class</input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @epascarello and Subham Jain! That worked! You guys are awesome. I appreciate your time, attention, and rapid response to the matter. Have a wonderful day!